# Soft bricked my Samsung Galaxy j2 Prime. I need help!

Tags: samsung, unbricking, restore, device-firmware, unrooting

First of all, I must clarify I'm not tech savy, I have some really basic knowledge but it's the same as nothing. I will do however try to follow up.

**The problem:**

I followed [this guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-samsung-galaxy-j2-prime-g532f-g532m-g532g-supersu-root-sm-g532f-m-g.3523090/) on how to quickly and effortlessly root my Samsung J2 Prime G532M. What I ended up getting was that [system apps every half second stop working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGltv.jpg), making my device inaccesible through home screen, slowing it down and making it almost unusable.

I have looked into tutorials but I just get completely lost, and *all of them require to wipe all data, which I really don't want to*. In case it's not possible, how do I know which one of [these stock firmware](https://www.sammobile.com/samsung/galaxy-j2-prime/firmware/SM-G532M/CTI/#SM-G532M) will work on my device?

**The main goal**

Is it possible to restore my firmware to how it was before without loosing my data? I didn't do a firmware backup because the tutorial never mentioned to.

I tried moving files to my PC from a USB cable, but most folders appear as empty when they clearly shouldn't (my Whatsapp stickers folders for example)

Comment: I think you should better ask the guide authors.

Comment: I did, they didn't reply so far. Besides, I don't think the author answers, it's a """"updated""" guide from 2016

Comment: About stock firmware version. I would try to flash the most recent one. Or it seems PDA column may refer to specific model modifications. Try to check whether Setting -> About phone includes a similar number. If yes then select firmware based on it.

Comment: get your files off device via *'adb pull -a /sdcard'* or if your device is rooted get a dump of whole userdata partition via *'adb exec-out "su -c cat /dev/block/dm-0 2> /dev/null" > userdata.img'* (or */dev/block/platform/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.msdc0/by-name/userdata* if not encrypted). If not rooted dump userdata partition from SP Flash in Tool (if not encrypted) you can mount ext4 disk image afterwards

Comment: btw there is TWRP linked in last post of the guide you followed. once you have dump of dm-0/userdata you can restore it from TWRP via *'adb push userdata.img /dev/block/mmcblk0p29'*

Comment: Hey @alecxs thank you! Unfortunattely I have already flashed it with a stock (but not approved) firmware. Still, thanks for taking your time